# why does this only run once instead of twice after making it as variable? bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have something like this...

I have three files.
two files which contains same variables but different values and a third file which executes commands such as `cd` to a certain place

my third file is called `init.sh` and looks something like

```
###############
# works perfectly if I do it this way
source db/abc.sh  # changes variable
source db/commands.sh

source db/def.sh  # changes variable
source db/commands.sh


###############
# does not work
RUN_COMMANDS=$(source db/commands.sh)

source db/1107556.sh  # changes variable
${RUN_COMMANDS}  # this does not run

source db/kunyuan.sh # changes variable
${RUN_COMMANDS}  # this runs
```

Reason I am doing this is so I can change the variables then run the same commands since the commands are the same but just different values for the variable.

Hopefully I am not doing anything stupid to think this way of using bash.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
RUN_COMMANDS=$(source db/commands.sh)
```

means "run the command `source db/commands.sh`, and store its output (= everything it printed to standard output) in the variable `RUN_COMMANDS`".

Instead, you seem to want:

```
RUN_COMMANDS=(source db/commands.sh)     # note -- no '$'

source db/1107556.sh
"${RUN_COMMANDS[@]}"

source db/kunyuan.sh
"${RUN_COMMANDS[@]}"
```

which sets `RUN_COMMANDS` to an *array* containing `source` and `db/commands.sh`, and then runs that array as a command (which is equivalent to running the command `source db/commands.sh`).

That said, you might want to consider writing a shell function:

```
function run-db-commands() {
    source "$1" && source db/commands.sh
}

run-db-commands db/1107556.sh
run-db-commands db/kunyuan.sh
```

Comment: ah! got it, and really thanks for the suggestions, the shell function you suggested would be way better and cleaner to look at too.  Thanks a lot~!